# Debug node_module with source map in Create React App application

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm implementing a react library and bundling it with rollup, which is properly generating the source map and linking it to the bundle.

For testing purposes, I have a react application generated with create-react-app, which is making use of my library. And After npm installing my dependency, I can see the bundle and the source maps located in node_modules directory.

Problem comes when I run it with npm start. Apparently the browser doesn't have access to the source map and I can only debug using the bundled version of my library.

Is there a way to debug a node_module of a CRA application, using its original source map without having to eject?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I also want to know...